# Joining 3 tables with WHERE clause in Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have problem with SQL in Android (SQLite).
I have three tables in relation many-to-many, suppose A, B and C, each has 30 records. I want to join these tables and after that use WHERE clause. I have written something like this code

```
SELECT *
FROM A
   JOIN B ON A.id=B.photoid 
   JOIN C ON B.urlid=C.id 
WHERE C.type=[SOME VALUE]
```

I have also tried this

```
SELECT *
FROM A
   LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.id=B.photoid 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.urlid=C.id AND C.type=[SOME VALUE]
```

and this

```
SELECT *
FROM A
   CROSS JOIN B
   CROSS JOIN C
WHERE A.id=B.photoid AND B.urlid=C.id AND C.type=[SOME VALUE]
```

These statements don't work in Android. They return 300 records.
What should I change? Is it bug or I do something wrong?

Comment: Why should 300 records be wrong? Show a few example rows and the output.

Comment: I found out that the problem is in `A.id=B.photoid`. `A.id` and `B.photoid` are Instagram photo id thus they are `TEXT` fields. My queries have problem with joining on `TEXT` fields. Is it normal?

Comment: Joins on text values work just fine. What problem do you think you have?

Comment: OK, I solved it. I had little mistake in `B.photoid`. My fault... sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without any additional data, but keep in mind that a `JOIN` operation will produce a row for each combination of a value in any of the tables involved. If you had 3 tables, each with 30 rows and you wouldn't be filtering any result, it should produce 27000 rows, but you're filtering by `A.id=B.photoid` and `B.urlid=C.id`, which might be producing a smaller set of rows.

In my opinion, that's not anything related to SQLite, but to your query instead. I'd try to make your set of values much smaller (for example, 5 per table) and run the same query, and see which results are being returned which shouldn't be, and try to modify your query to make it discard all those unwanted results.